# How to efficiently reduce a list: Entries which are not contained in other entries

Tags: python, string, performance, python-2.7, search

I'm new to Python. My code for reducing a list of strings takes a long time to execute. It functions to find: only those strings in a list which aren't partial matches of other strings in the same list. Is there a more efficient form of this code?

The code below seemed to work better than the following: `any(item1 for item in my_list1 if item1.startswith(item1) or item1.endswith(item1))` from a related question ([Python list lookup with partial match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117318/python-list-lookup-with-partial-match)). Am I using any wrong?

Right now, I can only find partial matches in my_list1 which begin or end other entries in my_list1. I'd like to find ALL partial matches, even center matches.

```
#My_list1 could be:
my_list=['abcd', 'abcde', 'abcdef', 'bcd', 'bcde', 'bcdef']

for item1 in my_list1:
    icount=0    
    for item2 in my_list1:
        if item2.startswith(item1): 
            icount+=1
        if icount>1:
            break
    if icount==1:
       my_list2.append(item1)
       print item1
```

Desired my_list2 would be:
`['abcdef']`

When I change the line

```
if item2.startswith(item1):
```

to

```
if item2 in item1:
```

I go from having thousands of results in my_list2 with few redundancies to zero results in my_list2

Comment: If your list is really the list of integers you show, your code won't work at all; `int` objects don't have a `.startswith()` method.

Comment: (Anyway, the operator you're looking for to see if a substring is in a string is `in`.)

Comment: Bad example, thanks. I'm always using lists of strings, even when dealing with integers.

Comment: @mattkaeo You should replace `if item2.startswith(item1)` with `if item1 in item2`, not `if item2 in item1`.

Comment: @dano YES! I went from 3443 items in my_list2 using startswith to 1439

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sort the list by the length of the entries prior to searching it. That way, you don't need to search the entire list for partial matches as you iterate over each entry, since you know any entries prior to the current entry won't be a partial match, because they're too short. Like this:

```
l = ['abcd', 'abcde', 'abcdef', 'bcd', 'bcde', 'bcdef']
s_l = sorted(l, key=len)
print("Sorted list is {}".format(s_l)
out = [val for i,val in enumerate(s_l)
         if not any(val in ent for ent in s_l[i+1:])]
print out
```

Output:

```
Sorted list is ['bcd', 'abcd', 'bcde', 'abcde', 'bcdef', 'abcdef']
['abcdef']
```

This piece might be confusing:

```
if not any(val in ent for ent in s_l[i+1:])
```

It's iterating over all indices after the current index (represented by `s_l[i+1:]`), and checking to see if the `val` substring is contained in any of the strings at each index (represented by `val in ent`). If any of those indices return `True` for the `val in ent` test, the `any` call will return `True`. So we're saying, add `val` to our `out` list if `val` is not a sub-string of any of the strings contained in `s_l`, starting after the current `s_l` index.