# Is there a way to exclude specific substrings when using str.contains?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

#### Background

I am analyzing a Pandas DataFrame that includes the title of different food recipes. My goal is to create categories for the recipe titles based on a keyword in the title.

For instance:
'Spicy Noodle Soup' would be in the **Soup** category,
'Sour Cream Apple Pie' would be in the **Pie** category.

I create DataFrames for each of these categories by using the following script

```
df[df['title'].str.contains('Soup', na=False, case=False)]
df[df['title'].str.contains('Pie', na=False, case=False)]
```

#### Problem

I want to exclude specific recipes that have the keyword within the string. The first example that came to mind was excluding 'pancake' from the **Cake** category. Although many would argue that pancake is a cake, I am not for the purpose of this excercise :) .

A non-optimal solution would be to use ' cake' as the substring, however this would exclude shortcakes, which I would like to include

#### Question

Is there way to exclude specific substrings when using the str.contains() method? Based on the documentation it doesn't seem like theres a built in way (I could be wrong)

Comment: You can do `' cake '`, but then you would miss `'shortcake'`.

Comment: Yes, I mention that in the problem. Cheesecake as well

Comment: [How to retrieve partial matches from a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64127140) you can use the `nltk` words corpus to make a bag of acceptable or not acceptable words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I can think of is to replace that specific string with `''`

```
exclude_words = ['pancake', 'cakefake']

df[df['title'].replace(exclude_words,'', regex=True)
              .str.contains('cake', case=False)
  ]
```

This approach will work better when you have a list of words that you want to exclude as illustrated above since you don't need to control where the `cake` appears relatively in your words.

Or use a negative look behind if you only have one `'pancake'` word for simpler syntax:

```
df[df['title'].str.contains('(?<!pan)cake')]
```

Test data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'title':['cheesecake', 'pancake','no cake']})
```

Output:

```
        title
0  cheesecake
2     no cake
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly, I also tested other & multiple prefixes to be excluded at the same time and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can also include a condition to exclude values. The implementation would be something like this. It is a bit costly implementation though.

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'name': ['Willard Morris', 'Al Jennings', 'Chris Cook'],
'age': [20, 19, 18],
'favorite_food': ['Cake', 'Pancake', 'Ice Cream']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)

new_df = df[df['favorite_food'].str.contains('cake', na=False, case=False)
            & ~df['favorite_food'].isin(['Pancake'])]

print ('raw-data df')
print (df)

print ('\nfiltered df for cake')
print (new_df)
```

The output of this will be:

```
raw-data df
             name  age favorite_food
0  Willard Morris   20          Cake
1     Al Jennings   19       Pancake
2      Chris Cook   18     Ice Cream

filtered df for cake
             name  age favorite_food
0  Willard Morris   20          Cake
```